# Installing new style files in Linux

Tags: packages, installing, linux

**Closure of this question was unnecessary**. My question is not a duplicate of the one linked to. My questions are Linux specific and ask for advice about using Kile on Linux. My question refers to *more* that style files. I have read the question that I have supposedly duplicated and *none of the replies answer my question*. Closure was unhelpful, misguided and basically unwelcoming.

I wanted to be able to cancel factors in the numerator and denominator with a dash. I searched this site and saw that I could use the package `cancel`. I tried to `\usepackage{cancel}`, but Kile didn't recognize it because it couldn't find the style file.

I found the web-page and have downloaded the style file `cancel.sty`. Sadly, I can't find where Kile keeps all of the style files. Even if I did find the folder, would I just cut-and-paste, or is there some more sophisticated process required to integrate new style files?

The problem is that I am a newbie to Linux and can't find where all of the files are kept. I found some commands for searching for files, but they either didn't work: the terminal claimed the (existing) file didn't exist, or the terminal started to list *every* file on my system.

- Where are my style files kept on Linux Mint, using Kile?
- Do I just cut-and-paste a new style file into the folder?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If you installed TeX Live via your package manager there is no reason to install `cancel` manually, it is provided by the [`texlive-latex-extra`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/all/texlive-latex-extra/filelist) package.

Comment: @dcmst Thanks for the reply. I have tried to *usepackage{texlive-latex-extra}* and I get the same error: 'texlive-latex-extra.sty' not found. Any ideas?

Comment: @dcmst has shown a link to ubuntu packages _not_ latex package hence cannot be used `\usepackage{texlive-latex-extra}`. Type at terminal `sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-extra` to install TeXLive extra packages from Ubuntu/mint package manager. Once you install you should get `cancel.sty` installed as it's part of the ubuntu texlive-latex-extra package. Type at terminal `kpsewhich cancel.sty` to know if `cancel.sty` exists or not. Note Kile is just a IDE not a TeX distro like TeXLive.

Comment: @texenthusiast Thank you so very much! Like I said: I'm a total Linux newbie. I followed your instructions and it all worded perfectly. I can confirm that the *cancel* package is up and running. Thank you for taking the time to help. I'm really happy now!

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about Linux Mint - on Gentoo which should be following Linux standards, I look under

```
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/
```

Don't forget to issue the `texhash` command as superuser after having added your style file.

You could also simply add `cancel.sty` to the working directory for your project, then it would be available for that project only.

On the newer versions of Mint (e.g. Sonya 18.02), when using texlive, it is under:

/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/

Comment: On Debian it's in `/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/` (Linux Mint is based on Debian).